# unknown type of date or time in web developing

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, web

I saw in a website request date format like this :

```
2020120321-20210003220330
```

its not epoch . what is this date format ? how I can convert it to human-readable format ?

Comment: `2020120321` -> `2020 12 03 21` I would guess, or today's date. Not sure what the 21 is - it might be the hour or it might be just a counter appended to it or something else. Don't know what the second part is - it might be time `20:21:00` or it might be some other type of identifier unconnected with time. An ID or something. It's not really possible to guess what all of this is without having the barest clue where you're seeing this and what sort of data are you working with.

Comment: What website? This seems like an error.

Comment: https://www.tgju.org/profile/price_dollar_rl    send request every 5 second

Comment: OK...multiple questions now: 1. Why do you think this is a date? 2. Why do you need to convert it to a human readable format at all? 3. How did you even get that value as *it shouldn't be possible?* If the value you show in your question is real, then there is no real way to figure out what the correct time is as it shows a completely incorrect time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like a range:

- `2020120321` - December 3rd, 2020 @ 21:00
- `-` to
- `20210003220330` - Mystery month 3rd, 2021 @ 22:03:30

Comment: @RsF That's already in my answer...

Comment: ty . and how i can create a string like the part two of this in php ?

Comment: @RsF Well `00` is not a real month so you would have to `echo date('Y00dHis');`

Answer (score 0):

From the format, it is pretty obvious that the format is yyyymmddhh. So for the first one it will be year 2020, month 12, day 3 hour 21. There are many ways how you can convert it to human readable format for example,

```
$timestamp = '2020120321';
$year = substr($timestamp, 0, 4);
$month = substr($timestamp, 4, 2);
$day = substr($timestamp, 6, 2);
$hour = substr($timestamp, 8, 2);
```

Comment: Is it obvious? Why would 21 be the hour? It might be an incremental ID added to the date - so this is the 21st message today. It might be a thread ID - logged by thread number 21. Might be just another ID that belongs to an item. We don't know *when* this data was shown, so it's incredibly hard to guess whether it happened around 9PM or not.

Comment: ty for answer . what about part two of string ? i mean after -

Comment: @VLAZ The OP mentioned its a date format. My assumption was based on that. year-month-day-hour-min-sec format is pretty common and the pattern in the question goes with that. But of-course there are other possibilities aswell.

Comment: @RsF the pattern of the second part looks like yyyymmddhhmmss. But as MonkeyZeus mentioned, then the month becomes 00 which does not make sense.